# Bayes' theorem selecting balls

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I'm trying to understand the solution of the problem defined [here](https://analyticsindiamag.com/a-guide-to-bayesian-statistics-in-python-for-beginners/). The problem statement is:

**Part 1** For example, suppose we have 2 buckets A and B. In bucket A we have 30 blue balls and 10 yellow balls, while in bucket B we have 20 blue and 20 yellow balls. We are required to choose one ball. What is the chance that we choose bucket A given that a blue ball was chosen?

**Part 2** We put back the ball chosen in Part 1. We choose another ball again, this time it turns out to be yellow. What is the probability that both times we choose the ball from bucket A?

I do not understand the solution of **Part 2**.

**Solution for Part 1**

Let $A,B$ be the events of selecting bucket A and B respectively. Let $Blue,Yellow$ be the events of selecting Blue and Yellow balls. We are asked to find $P(A|Blue)$. By Bayes' theorem

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A|Blue) &= \frac{P(Blue|A)P(A)}{P(Blue)} = \frac{\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}}{P(Blue|A)P(A)+P(Blue|B)P(B)} \\
&= \frac{\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}}
=0.6
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly we can get
$$
P(B|Blue) = 0.4  \qquad P(A|Yellow) = \frac{1}{3} \qquad P(B|Yellow) = \frac{2}{3} 
$$

**My attempt at solving Part 2**

It seems to me that we have two events.

Event $C$: $A$ | $Yellow$,        that is: Ball comes from Bucket A given ball is Yellow

Event $D$: $A$ | $Blue$,        that is: Ball comes from Bucket A given ball is Blue

It seems that we are looking for $P(C|D)$, the probability that the yellow ball is chosen from bucket A, given that first we have chosen blue ball from bucket A. So we are looking for

$$
P(C|D) = \frac{P(D|C)P(C)}{P(D)}
$$

And I have no idea what to do with the $P(D|C)$ term. The other two are calculated before.

In the solution they have provided, it seems they are doing

$$
\begin{align}
P(C|D) &= P(A|Yellow\Big{|}A|Blue)\\
       &= \frac{P(Yellow|A)P(A|Blue)}{P(Yellow)}\\
       &= \frac{0.25*0.6}{P(Yellow|A)P(A|Blue)+P(Yellow|B)P(B|Blue)}\\
       &= \frac{0.15}{0.25*0.6+0.5*0.4} \\
       &= 0.4285
\end{align}
$$

But I can find no logic in this argument.

Could someone please explain how I can solve part 2?

Comment: Part 1 seems to be missing a constraint.  In Part 1, was the ball that was chosen at random turn out to be blue?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, a blue ball was chosen. I've edited the problem statement to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm, if your question is just how to solve part 2, then since he returned the blue ball back to A, we return to the original situation! That is, event 1 and event 2 are independent. So, $P(A|Yellow)$ given we first took a blue ball from A, then return it to back to A, is simply $P(A|Yellow)$

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes I thought so too, but since they're building off the second example I thought they must be correct. If you have a better source for Bayes' theorem, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Without stating the [priors](https://jonathanweisberg.org/vip/priors.html), it is also impossible to solve the exercise.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes I disagree about the independence of event 1 and event 2.  See the Addendum to my answer.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch It seems reasonable to presume that at the start of the problem, the chance of bucket A being chosen is $(1/2)$.  I do agree that without that assumption, part 1 itself can not be attacked.  Once you make that assumption, everything falls into place.  See the answer that I left.

Comment: @user You also need to assume that each ball has the same probability of being picked. It is careless that these assumptions are not stated in the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me that we have two events.
>
> Event C: A | Yellow,       that is: Ball comes from Bucket A given ball is Yellow
>
> Event D: A | Blue,      that is: Ball comes from Bucket A given ball is Blue

Those are *not* events.  Conditioning is an aspect of the probability measure, not the event space.  It is not a set operation.

The events of interest are "selecting bucket A", "firstly drawing a blue ball", and "secondly drawing a yellow ball".  Designate these as $A$, $B$, and $Y$.

> In bucket A we have 30 blue balls and 10 yellow balls, while in bucket B we have 20 blue and 20 yellow balls.

So we have $\mathsf P(B\mid A)=3/4$, and $\mathsf P(B\mid A^\complement)=2/4$.  Since the selection of the second ball is *conditionally* independent of the selection of the first, we also have $\mathsf P(Y\mid A,B)=\mathsf P(Y\mid A) = 1/4$, and $\mathsf P(Y\mid A^\complement,B)=\mathsf P(Y\mid A^\complement) = 2/4$.

---

For Part 1, Bayes' Rule says :

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid A)~\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B\mid A)~\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\mid A^\complement)~\mathsf P(A^\complement)}\\&=\dfrac{\tfrac 34\tfrac 12}{\tfrac 34\tfrac12+\tfrac24\tfrac 12}\\&=\dfrac 35\end{align}$$

---

Part 2 is much the same.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B, Y) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(Y\mid A, B)~\mathsf P(A\mid B)}{\mathsf P(Y\mid A, B)~\mathsf P(A\mid B)+\mathsf P(Y\mid A^\complement, B)~\mathsf P(A^\complement\mid B)}\\&=\dfrac{\tfrac 14\tfrac 35}{\tfrac 14\tfrac35+\tfrac24\tfrac 25}\\&=\dfrac 37\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it is starting to make sense for me. Defining events correctly is of paramount importance. I think that we should start with $P(A|Y,B)$ just like you did in your previous comment. Then it all starts to make sense. Finally, it seems that $A^\complement$ means the complement of $A$. I hadn't seen that notation before,being used to $A'$.

Answer (score 2):

For part 2, I had trouble understanding both your attempted solution as well as the offered solution.  My trouble with the offered solution might be caused by my misinterpreting the problem.

Let $R$ denote the event that the ball(s) came from bucket $A$.

Let $S$ denote the event that the ball(s) came from bucket $B$.

Let $T$ denote the event that the first ball chosen was blue.

Let $U$ denote the event that the first ball chosen was blue and that the second ball chosen was yellow.

The way that I read part (2), which might not represent the intent of the problem composer, is that you are supposed to assume that both balls came from the same bucket.

In part (1), you are trying to calculate $p(R|T)$.

The way that I interpret part (2), you are trying to calulate $p(R|U)$, where it is to be assumed that both balls were chosen from the same bucket.

So, $\displaystyle p(R|U) = \frac{p(R ~\text{and} ~U)}{p(U)}.$

To calculate $p(U)$, you have to consider two possibilities:

- Bucket $A$ was chosen, the first ball selected was blue, then the next ball selected was yellow. 
  Probability of this happening is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{30}{40} \times \frac{10}{40} = \frac{3}{32}.$
- Bucket $B$ was chosen, the first ball selected was blue, then the next ball selected was yellow. 
  Probability of this happening is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{20}{40} \times \frac{20}{40} = \frac{1}{8} = \frac{4}{32}.$

Therefore,

$$\frac{p(R ~\text{and} ~U)}{p(U)} = \frac{\frac{3}{32}}{\frac{3}{32} + \frac{4}{32}} = \frac{3}{7}.$$

As it turns out, my answer happens to agree with the offered solution, so it looks like I interpreted the question correctly.  However, I am (still) unable to decipher the posted analysis to the solution.

---

**Addendum**
Actually, I have now figured out how to reverse-engineer the offered analysis.

You are supposed to use part 1 to conclude that the chances of bucket $A$ rather than bucket $B$ being chosen has **changed** from $(1/2)$ to $(3/5) = 0.6.$  This is a valid but somewhat sophisticated approach.  For students fairly new to Bayes Theorem, I would not post a solution that uses this type of analysis.  However, the analysis is valid.

You are then supposed to compute

$$p(A|\text{yellow}) = \frac{p(A ~\text{and yellow})}{p(\text{yellow})} = \frac{\frac{3}{5} \times \frac{1}{4}}{\left[\frac{3}{5} \times \frac{1}{4}\right] + 
\left[\frac{2}{5} \times \frac{1}{2}\right]} = \frac{3}{7}.$$

Comment: It's : $$\small\begin{align}p(A\mid Y,B) &=\dfrac{p(A\mid B)~p(Y\mid A,B)}{p(Y\mid B)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{p(A\mid B)~p(Y\mid A)}{p(A\mid B)~p(Y\mid A)+p(A^\complement\mid B)~p(Y\mid A^\complement)}\end{align}$$(NB $p(Y\mid A,B)=p(Y\mid A)$ because $Y$ is conditionally independent of $B$ for a given bucket.). And of course we can show:$$\small\begin{align}p(A\mid Y,B)&=\dfrac{p(A)~p(B\mid A)~p(Y\mid A)}{p(A)~p(B\mid A)~p(Y\mid A)+p(A^\complement)~p(B\mid A^\complement)~p(Y\mid A^\complement)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{p(A)~p(B,Y\mid A)}{p(A)~p(B,Y\mid A)+p(A^\complement)~p(B,Y\mid A^\complement)}\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Interesting comment, thanks.

Comment: user2661923: I follow your first answer. I have some intuition about your second answer, but not enough
@GrahamKemp: Your answer is close to what I'm looking for. But I'm having trouble following the steps, perhaps because your notation is slightly different.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Re Nachiket's last comment, I do not have any formal training in Probability; so I am guided by intuition (and reverse engineering).  It would take me some time to have a *confident* understanding of your comment.  So, I am unable to help Nachiket, with respect to your comment.

Comment: @Nachiket Unclear what you are saying in your last comment.  See the comment that I just left for Graham Kemp.  Do you have any specific questions for me, about any part of my answer?

Comment: @user2661923 No specific questions for you. I'm grateful for your answer and for supplying intuition.